# How to save incoming file in bottle api to hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, bottle, pyhdfs-client

I am defining `bottle` api where I need to accept a file from the client and then save that file to HDFS on the local system.

The code looks something like this.

```
@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    upload = request.files.upload
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)

    save_path = "/data/{user}/{filename}".format(user=USER, filename=name)

    hadoopy.writetb(save_path, upload.file.read())
    return "File successfully saved to '{0}'.".format(save_path)
```

The issue is, the `request.files.upload.file` is an object of type `cStringIO.StringO` which can be converted to a `str` with a `.read()` method. But the `hadoopy.writetb(path, content)` expects the content to be some other format and the server sticks at that point. It doesn't give exception, it doesn't give error or any result. Just stands there as if it was in infinite loop.

Does anyone know how to write incoming file in bottle api to HDFS?

Comment: So, you're rewriting WebHDFS, basically?

Comment: No. I just want to write bottle apis and one of those be file upload and read from and to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

From the [hadoopy documentation](http://www.hadoopy.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#putting-data-on-hdfs), it looks like the second parameter to `writetb` is supposed to be an iterable of pairs; but you're passing in bytes.

> ...the hadoopy.writetb command which takes an iterator of key/value pairs...

Have you tried passing in a pair? Instead of what you're doing,

```
hadoopy.writetb(save_path, upload.file.read())  # 2nd param is wrong
```

try this:

```
hadoopy.writetb(save_path, (path, upload.file.read()))
```

(I'm not familiar with Hadoop so it's not clear to me what the semantics of `path` are, but presumably it'll make sense to someone who knows HDFS.)

Comment: Path would just be any filesystem path string

Comment: Yes. Path is just a string like `hdfs://localhost:8082/root/data/files/foo` but the thing is that `upload.file.read()` is giving string which `writetb` is not accepting that!

Comment: @KeyurGolani Did you read the API for `writetb`? The second param is supposed to be a tuple, not a string. I edited my answer to make it clearer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes. I have read the documentation. It says that the second argument is `iterator of (key, value)` and in this case the question is posted just because I don't know what is an iterator of (key, value) because all I have is a StringIO object and ability to convert it into a string. I have tried `hadoopy.writetb(save_path, (path, upload.file.read()))` already and I tried it again after your suggestion. It doesn't work. The server goes into some infinite loop and doesn't return anything back.

Comment: Since `writetb` clearly expects an iterator of pairs as its second argument, I would never expect the code in your question to work. You may want to update your Q with code that isn't working for you but that does conform to hadoopy's api. Good luck!